# Carregar uma variável de outra funtion

Tags: matlab

Tenho a seguinte dúvida que não consegui resolver através de pesquisa.
Tenho uma função que dentro dela crio uma variável para realizar uma contagem, e mais tarde preciso do valor final desse contagem noutra função.
A função onde criei o contador é:

```
function haSolucao=Passo0(MCobertura,numAmbulancias,numIdosos)
```

E este contador(`inputCounter`) vai ser usado neste excerto da função para ser incrementado:

```
while inputCounter <= numIdosos
idF = str2double(input('Indique os idosos fragilizados,insira "0" quando terminar: ', 's'));
if idF==0
    break;
end
while isnan(idF) || fix(idF) ~= idF
    idF = str2double(input('Insira um número inteiro!: ', 's'));
end
fragil(1,inputCounter)=idF;
inputCounter = inputCounter+1;
end
```

E de seguida precisava de chamar o valor final deste contador nesta função:

```
function solucao = Passo1(MCobertura,numAmbulancias,numIdosos)
```

E para tal tentei:

```
inputCounter = Passo0(inputCounter);
counterCheck = inputCounter.inputCounter;

 for k = 1:counterCheck
         if j == fragil(k)
             porCobrir(j)=1;
         else
             porCobrir(j)=0;
         end
     end
```

Porém ele não consegue encontrar a variável.Também tentei definir a variável com

```
global inputCounter;
```

Mas também não resulta.

Answer (score 0):

Tudo depende de como você faz a pesquisa, o site do matlab é uma boa fonte de recursos, apesar de ser em inglês!

Existem algumas maneiras de resolver este problema, vou colocar os métodos que eu usaria 
 na ordem que eu recomendo usar, mas isso depende muito do que se está fazendo. No final faço uma breve discussão da razão das sua tentativas não funcionarem.

- Usando saída [múltipla](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html) da função

De longe a maneira mais facil e segura de usar, assim você evita carregar variáveis que você não precisa as outras vezes que chama a função. Basta usar a declaração descrita no [manual](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function.html):

```
function [output_principal, meu_index] = foo(bar).
% Function here ...

%Em OUTRO lugar, Para chamar os resultados
[a,b]=foo(1)
%ou
a=foo(1)
%se quiser apenas o segundo valor
[~,b]=foo(1)
```

- [Structure array](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html) ou [Cell array](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html)

Esses dois tipos de array permitem carregar tipos diferentes de variáveis em apenas uma *matriz*. Nos dois casos você pode usar a `struct` ou `cell` como entrada e saída das funções, porém cada vez que for utilizar um dos valores é necessário usar a chamada apropriada. Vou demonstrar apenas para a `struct`, olhe o manual pra usar a `cell`.

```
function mystruct = foo(bar).
%dentro da funcão, quando já tiver os números que você quer 
mystruct.index= index;
mystruct.output=output;


%Em OUTRO lugar, Para chamar os resultados
aaa=foo(1);
aaa = 
  struct with fields:

 output: [2×2 double]
  index: 1

%Claro que lá tem seus números e nomes!
%Para obter os valores, use o esquema similar a declaração  
index=mystruct.index
output_principal=mystruct.output
```

- [Global](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html)

No último caso, e as vezes é necessário, você pode usar  declara ela como `global`. Porém este é algo que facilmente pode dar problemas, pois a variável pode ser alterada de maneira diferente pelas diferentes chamadas e ela precisa ser limpa da maneira apropriada (`clear global variable`).
Caso você *realmente precise* utilizar uma variavel global ela precisa ser declarada `global` em [todas as funcões](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html).

---

> Problemas

1. `inputCounter = Passo0(inputCounter);`

Isto funciona, desde que não seja a mesma funcão `Passo0` que você está chamando inicialmente. Usar o nome da variável não dá diferença na saída, pois ele apenas usa os valores que estão naquela variável, não seu nomes ou referencias (acho que pode ser feito via objetos). Além disso, você está com o número de entradas diferente em `Passo0`. Isso pode ser [trabalhado](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html), porém ainda assim cada chamada da função deve ser independente, deixando assim o valor do índice sem a referencia que você quer.

2. `CounterCheck = inputCounter.inputCounter;`

Se isso não está declarado como uma estrutura e já inicializado, isto dará problemas.
Fazer `a=foo(a)` não é um problema, mas ele irá pegar o valor de `a`, usar na funcão `foo` e sobrescrever esta saida (qualquer que ela seja) em `a`. Se a saida não for uma estrutura, isso não irá funcionar na sintaxe que você colocou.

3. Global

Provavelmente, você não deve ter declarado global em todos os lugares, neste caso matlab não tem acesso aos valores em todas as funções.